# how to solved table catalog_product_entiry issue : M2

Tags: magento2, category-products, entities

I found there is issue with `row_id` and `entity_id` in this `catalog_product_entity`.  I'm not able to assign product to category, it gives this error:

> Something went wrong while saving the category.SQLSTATE[23000]:
>   Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails (`mydb`.`catalog_category_product`,
>   CONSTRAINT `CAT_CTGR_PRD_PRD_ID_SEQUENCE_PRD_SEQUENCE_VAL` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`product_id`) REFERENCES `sequence_product` (`sequence_value`) ON
>   DELETE CA), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product`
>   (`category_id`,`product_id`,`position`) VALUES (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?),
>   (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?,
>   ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?), (?, ?, ?)

Table values in database is:

[image]

Comment: Can you please let me know how you have resolved this issue

Comment: i have empty all tables of products and categories.

Answer (score 0):

We have faced the similar issue on Magento commerce after upgrading to 2.1.6 to 2.1.17. After investigating further, I found Magento_VisualMerchandiser creating the issue.
When I disabled it, no sql error is displaying when assigning product to a categories.

Although this is not the solution, But it will be help full.

Ref- https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/16227

Comment: yes, there is some issue with save position: Magento\VisualMerchandiser\Block\Adminhtml\Category\Merchandiser\Tile

Comment: after comment of save position script, assign product to category functionality is working good

Comment: There are many dependencies for this extension. 10 other modules require it, so we can't just disable it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The problem is, that the `sequence_value` does not exist in the table `sequence_product` and therefor the error is thrown.

Just add the product id into that table in the correct place at its order position! Don't just put it at the bottom, this will mess everything up.